Why the constant item of an exponential map's solution is the trajectory at point 0
I am reading a paper about Lie group and Lie algebra, a micro lie theory for state etimation in robotics by Joan Sola.
In this paper, a few equations are not quite obvious to derive. My question comes from equation (13) of the paper. Before bring them here, some concetps would be given here.
$\mathcal{M}$ is Lie group's manifold,
$\mathcal{X}$ is the point on $\mathcal{M}$, i.e. $\mathcal{X} \in \mathcal{M}$,
With the rules of multiplicative group, there is $\mathcal{X}^{-1}\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{E}$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is the unit element,
Differentiating both sides of the unit element gives
$\dot{\mathcal{X}^{-1}}\mathcal{X} +\mathcal{X}^{-1}\dot{\mathcal{X}} = 0$
Further, in the paper a definition of Lie algebra is in the form as
$\mathbf{v}^\wedge = \dot{\mathcal{X}^{-1}}\mathcal{X} =-\mathcal{X}^{-1}\dot{\mathcal{X}}$. This turns into
$\dot{\mathcal{X}} = \mathcal{X} \mathbf{v}^\wedge$.
For a constant $\mathbf{v}$, this ODE's solution is
$\mathcal{X}(t) = \mathcal{X}(0)\mathbf{v}^\wedge t$.
What I cannot understand is that why $\mathcal{X}(0)$ is the constant item of this solution?

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.01537

The notation here and in the paper is a little vague. You say $\mathcal{X}$ is an element of the group but then differentiate it which doesn't make sense. It is also incredibly hard to read $\mathbf{v}^\wedge t$ as anything but $\mathbf{v}^t$. They really should have written it $t\mathbf{v}^\wedge$.
What is true is that if $\mathcal{X}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{M}$ is a parametrised curve in the Lie group then translating $\dot{\mathcal{X}}(t)$ by $\mathcal{X}^{-1}(t)$ gives an element of the Lie algebra. For a matrix Lie group this can be calculated as $\mathcal{X}^{-1}(t)\dot{\mathcal{X}}(t)$ (otherwise you have no way to multiply elements of the Lie group and Lie algebra together).
Also note the solution should be $\mathcal{X}(t) = \mathcal{X}(0)\exp(t\mathbf{v}^\wedge)$ as otherwise the right hand side is not an element of the group.
As to why $\mathcal{X}(0)$ appears in the solution, that is simple. You want it to equal $\mathcal{X}(0)$ when $t=0$.

Thanks to this answer, @Callum.
